# Blazor Server get current logged user when EF DbContext execute select data query

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, blazor-server-side

I build blazor server multi tenant application and I wants to use HasQueryFilter in entity framework DbContext for predefined filter with TenantId. Ofcourse I have connected User with tenant. I created CurrentTenatnProvider which has method GetCurrentTenatnId. In this mehtod i use AuthentificationStateProvider and call GetAuthenticationStateAsync(). Ofcourse i get the error ''GetAuthenticationStateAsync was called before SetAuthenticationState".  I Cannot use IHttpContextAccessor because in Azure app I get null reference exception.

Is there any other possibility  how to get CurrentUser in time when  DbContext execute select data query?

I was thinking about cache CurrnetUser but there is problem with cache key.CurrentTenatnProvider service is registered as scoped service. There is Id attribute which is set in constructor. And then is used as cache key. But this approach does not working  and I get the same error.
It si possible get signal-r connection identificator and use it as cache key?
I spended 2 days with test lots of combination and read lots of documentation but unfortunately I didn't find any solution. I will be very grateful for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this a few ways but the simplest way I could find was retrieving my user from the database in the `MainLayout.razor` file during `OnInitializedAsync()` and passing it in a fixed cascading parameter `<CascadingValue Name="CurrentUser" IsFixed="true" Value="UserId">`. From there, I could reference it where needed in any child component.

Comment: Thanks for your replay, bud I use IOC/DI and I need current user in DbContext. I have no problem with components.

Comment: Can you describe the app flow better?

Answer (score 0):

finally I found solution! From my view it is bug! Problem is because services.AddDbContextFactory is registered as Singleton. I create my own implementation of IDbContext factory and register it as Scoped. After this change everything’s works perfect. When I change registration scope of DbContextFactory to singleton, I get the error: GetAuthenticationStateAsync was called before SetAuthenticationState.

My DbContextFactory

```
public class BlazorContextFactory<TContext> : IDbContextFactory<TContext> where TContext : DbContext
    {
        private readonly IServiceProvider provider;

        public BlazorContextFactory(IServiceProvider provider)
        {
            this.provider = provider;
        }

        public TContext CreateDbContext()
        {
            if (provider == null)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException(
                    $"You must configure an instance of IServiceProvider");
            }

            return ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<TContext>(provider);
        }
    }
```

My StartUp

```
public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddScoped<ApplicationDbContext>();
            services.AddScoped<IDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext>, BlazorContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext>>();

            services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

            services.AddRazorPages();
            services.AddServerSideBlazor();
            services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, RevalidatingIdentityAuthenticationStateProvider<IdentityUser>>();
            services.AddSingleton<WeatherForecastService>();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
                endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
                endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
            });
        }
    }
```

I hope it's help other peoples! I spend 6 days with this problem :(